# Is there any test(quiz) description format?

Tags: api, standards, specifications

In the field of automation of education there SCORM specification and Tin Can API. Is there something like that or any standard or format for describing and storing tests (especially psychological). On the Internet you can find a lot of tests implemented in the form of applications, as well as programs and services that allow you to create your tests. But I could not find such an application in which you can download ready-made tests in any format.

Question: Is there some kind of format description of tests and, if so, where you can download these tests (eg, Amthauer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard that describes test questions so that those questions can be rendered in any conformant tool?

If I've understood correctly, you're looking for [QTI](http://www.imsglobal.org/question/).

Comment: Thank you. You have understood correctly. Other question: is QTI supports describe specific algorhitm of calculation of the test results. I go to read.